# modify every file found with `find`

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder with a bunch of `.svg` files.
I want to modify each svg file inside the folder in the following way:

- swap `#000000` with `currentColor`
- add `class` attribute with value based on filename (eg. for file named `icon-super-cool.svg` I want `class="icon-super-cool"`

here's where I've gotten to after hours of googling:

```sh
find ./ -name \*.svg -exec sed -i '' -e "s/#000000/currentColor/g;s/<svg/<svg class=\"icon ${name}\"/g" {} +
```

The colour replace part works fine. When it comes to the class attribute, every single icon get the same class attribute with `${name}` of the 1st file it processes.

Any help and explanation of what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

PS. working on a mac environment.

Comment: Use `xmlstarlet` or another tool that manipulates XML documents, not sed.

Comment: _"${name} of the 1st file it processes"_ would be _"the value of `$name` shell variable"_ What do you want to do? add a class called `path/file.svg" to your icons?

Comment: Is it `#000000` or `#3F505A`? Is `icon` part of the file name or do you want to prepend it to the file basename? Is it `icon name` or `icon-name` or `icon-icon-name`? Please answer by editing your question, not in comments.

Comment: Don't try doing the processing in the argument passed to `find`.  Write a script that processes a single file and invoke it in `find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your attempt:

1. In the `exec` action of `find` the name of the found file is represented by `{}`, not `${name}`.
2. Even with `{}` the class will end with `.svg`, not what you want.
3. Even with `{}` the class will contain the full file path (`./foo/bar/baz.svg`), not what you want.

The following assumes you want the class name to be `icon-name` where `name` is the basename of the file without the `.svg` extension:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.svg' -exec bash -c \
  'b=$(basename -s.svg "$1"); \
   sed -i "" "s/#000000/currentColor/g;s/<svg/<svg class=\"icon-$b\"/g" "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Or, as suggested by Charles, to reduce the number of bash runs:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.svg' -exec bash -c \
  'for f in "$@"; do b=$(basename -s.svg "$f"); \
   sed -i "" "s/#000000/currentColor/g;s/<svg/<svg class=\"icon-$b\"/g" "$f"; done' _ {} +
```

If performance is really an issue, and you want to process several files at once (`{} +` instead of `{} \;`), things are difficult with `sed` because the class replacement string is not constant (not impossible, though, but this would be horrible). But GNU `awk` can make it:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.svg' -exec awk -i inplace '\
  BEGINFILE {s=gensub(/^(.*\/)?(.*)\.svg$/,"<svg class=\"icon-\\2\"",1,FILENAME)} \
  {gsub(/#000000/,"currentColor"); gsub(/<svg/,s); print}' {} +
```

The first block (`BEGINFILE`) preprocesses each file name to build the class replacement string and the second performs the replacements. This should be the fastest of all (not tested).

The two first solutions should work even with the default versions of `find`, `sed`, `basename` and `bash` that come with macOS. For the last one you absolutely need a decently recent version of GNU `awk` (see MacPorts or HomeBrew).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It mostly worked for me, but the `.svg` extensions weren't being stripped. I did a quick search on google into basename, and modified `b=$(basename -s=.svg "$f");` to `b=$(basename -s .svg "$f");` which seems to do the trick!

Comment: My bad. I mixed up between long and short options. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a small script (save e.g. as `script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
for path in "$@"; do
    sed -i "" -e "s/#3F505A/currentColor/g;s/<svg/<svg class=\"icon-$(basename -s ".svg" "${path}")\"/g" "${path}"
done
```

and then call it from `find` like this:

```
find . -name '*.svg' -exec ./script.sh {} +
```

Comment: Consider putting a `for` loop in the script to iterate over arguments (`for name in "$@"; do`) so you could use `-exec ./script {} +` and don't need to start a copy of bash per file.

Comment: (Also, `./script` vs `./script.sh` is a very deliberate distinction; see [the #bash IRC channel's factoid on the topic](https://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh), and [an essay to which it has linked for the last decade+](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/); bash scripts are not _sh_ scripts, and having extensions on command names is not common -- you run `pip`, not `pip.py`; `ls`, not `ls.elf`)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added the for loop, thank you. But I don't understand what you meant about `script.sh`. The name of the script is just something I chose for the answer, it can be whatever you like. But I added to text that the name is just a suggestion.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I added `$(basename ...)` to handle this, thank you

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I changed it to remove `.svg` file extension